# Why does my variable gets undefined in normal run but gets defined in debug mode after assigning in Promise.then method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a react function bundled in webpack that resizes image files. I am calling default exported function for resizing. I get the resized image file inside then method of promise which is resolved successfully. But after I assign the value I cant use it anymore it gets undefined after. Here is my code;

```
var filetoupload;
imageresizer(item.file).then((value) => {
    filetoupload = value;
     });
var anotherinstance=filetoupload;
item.upload.formData.append('files[]',filetoupload);
```

Here filetoupload variable is correct in browser debug if I just stop after the code execution but gets undefined in normal run.
Why is that?
My react code is below:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import React from "react";
import Resizer from "react-image-file-resizer";
const resizeFile = (file) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(
      file,
      80,
      80,
      "JPEG",
      80,
      0,
      (uri) => {
        resolve(uri);
      },
      "file"
    );
  });


export default function resize(file) {
    return resizeFile(file);
 }
```

Comment: using a `.then` method ... e.g. `promiseIam.then(val=> console.log(val))`

Comment: I use the then method to get the data it gets the data without a problem, it works. But when I try to add it to formData with append method it gets undefined. what could be the reason for it?@KcH

Comment: Not sure can you add the code that you tried by editing the question

Comment: edited it please check it now. @KcH

Comment: It would be `undefined` as the value is not yet available, you can put the code inside `.then` and append in there ...